# Tableau, can't publish to server

Tags: tableau-api

edit: Sorry about the wrong title before. StackOverflow had saved an old question I was going to ask, and I didn't notice the title

I'm working with Tableau and have created a couple of Dashboards and have included a data source. The Data source is fairly big, around 10.000.000 rows.

My problem is that when I try to publish it to Tableau Server, it gets stuck at "Sending data to server" (See included picture). The server is not down as I can publish other Dashboards, where a smaller data source is included.

Has someone here had similar problems? In that case how can I fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I recommend letting your Tableau Server admin know about your problem They can probably help.

Comment: is this connection is live or extracted data source?

Comment: It's on an extracted data source. Waiting for our server guy to come back from vacation as I suspect it has something to do with our setup of Tableau server

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cut your datasource to 1 raw and put all data back when it will be already published. It's should work for sources like table or views in database for example.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment,

I found out the problem, and forgot I had this question here. It was a server issue where the amount of data allowed to be transferred was limitid, which caused an error. Increasing the limit fixed the issue

Comment: Just curious, how did you go about "increasing the limit" to address this issue? I'm encountering the same issue and my IT folks aren't sure which setting they're supposed to change on the Tableau server.